# I can not get a list<> using Jquery.ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I hope anyone tell me what's wrong on below code , and why it is not working .

webmethod in aspx.cs page .

```
    [webmethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Problem> GetProblems()
    {
        List<Problem> allproblems = new List<Problem>();
        using (TMEntities tm = new TMEntities())
        {
            allproblems = tm.Problems.ToList();    
        }
       return allproblems;
    }
```

and below is HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetProblems",
                data: "{}",
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

when i run the application nothing happened and when i press ctrl+shift+j to see the errors in browser , below error appeared

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: How do you expect to redirect to page method in ajax url ? Right the url WebForm1.aspx?GetProblems=true after that check in page_load for Response parameter GetProblems if it is true call method GetProblems.

Comment: What do you see when you debug your `GetProblems` method? (Set a breakpoint at its start, and then run the web app under the debugger.)

Comment: Since it is running on local, on your debug (client) tool , click on network tab and see the 500 error url, youw ill find the exact error why the server is returning 500. There could be any reason, some Dll is missing or anything else. Thus, the client debug tool will give you the reason. Make sure to run your application as DEBUG mode that you will be doing anyways.

Comment: @mybirthname please clarify more

Comment: @Richard nothing happened , step into and step over are dimmed /disabled

Comment: @codebased it shows an error in method : [GetProblems
/WebForm1.aspx
POST
500
Internal Server Error
text/html
jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
Script]

Comment: Please press  ctrl-alt-P (attach to process) on visual studio, and attach w3wp.exe , make a breakpoint and debug.

Comment: Is that `[webmethod]` a typo (re: `[WebMethod]`)?

Comment: @codebased ,w3wp.exe not found on the list .

Comment: @edsf it is a WebMethod , i changed it to WebMethod and still the same problem :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2faa92k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is your TMEntities constructor intializing `Problems` property ? 
if not then null reference exception in below line !

```
allproblems = tm.Problems.ToList();
```

If not above issue then Is your `Problem` class have any serialization issues? check it once

Comment: i try to run the same code on page load and make the datasource of a gridview equal allproblems .
gridview1.datasource=allproblems;
gridview1.databind();
it worked fine , but doesn't work with ajax :( , please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
[webmethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Problem> GetProblems()
    {
        List<Problem> allproblems = new List<Problem>();
        using (TMEntities tm = new TMEntities())
        {
            allproblems = tm.Problems.ToList();    
        }
       return allproblems;
    }
```

i check your javascript code . this code is ok. bt problem is c# code.

Please change [webmethod] to  `[WebMethod]`. I hope solve your problem. if not solve please give me your `Problem` and `TMEntities` class structure.

Comment: good notice , i changed it to WebMethod but still the same problem :( , ...........i try to run the same code on page load and make the datasource of a gridview equal allproblems . gridview1.datasource=allproblems; gridview1.databind(); it worked fine , but doesn't work with ajax :( , please help me

Comment: please use jQuery  datatable. Please Mail your full project. I try to solve your problem.

Comment: sbanerjee.cse@gmail.com